# How to scrape a PowerBI table from a website using python

Tags: web-scraping, powerbi, click

I have been trying to scrape the PowerBI table from this URL in python and have been unable to do so:

https://www.iadb.org/en/who-we-are/transparency/sanctions-system/sanctioned-firms-and-individuals

The page asks to click on ellipsis for downloading the table but the ellipsis itself is unclickable.
The table when viewed as a new window opens as this URL:

https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiYjhlOWUxMzItODE5YS00NTg2LWEyNmUtNmQ3YmNkODBiZDIxIiwidCI6IjlkZmIxYTA1LTVmMWQtNDQ5YS04OTYwLTYyYWJjYjQ3OWU3ZCIsImMiOjF9

I tried inspecting the developer tools for the tags but have been unsuccessful in doing so. The program keeps throwing errors since the ellipsis in unclickable and I am not able to simply scrap the PowerBI table.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.iadb.org/en/who-we-are/transparency/sanctions-system/sanctioned-firms-and-individuals"

# Set up the webdriver (assuming Chrome)
chrome_driver_path = "path"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# Set the download directory to the current working directory

options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

# Create a Chrome driver without specifying executable_path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

try:
    # Open the URL
    driver.get(url)

    # Wait for the grid to load (you may need to adjust the timeout)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "powerbi-frame"))
    )

    # Switch to the Power BI iframe
    iframe = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "powerbi-frame")
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    # Find the ellipsis menu and click it
    ellipsis_menu = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'ellipsis')]"))
    )
    ellipsis_menu.click()

    # Find and click the download option in the ellipsis menu
    download_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class, 'download-option')]"))
    )
    download_option.click()

finally:
    # Close the browser window
    driver.quit()
```